# An item with the same key has already been added. Key: forceget to get GetModelviewPropertiesAsync

Tags: .net, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I am using Forge Autodesk .NET library(version 1.9.0) to get the metadata of a translated file. I am using the below method as the metadata_properties is large for the file.

```
DynamicJsonResponse propertiesResponse = await derivativeApiInstance.GetModelviewPropertiesAsync
                                                                              (ForgeFileURN,                                                                               viewGUID,
                                                                              "gzip",
                                                                              null,
                                                                              false,
                                                                              true);
```

but I am getting error - **An item with the same key has already been added. Key: forceget**. Can anyone please help me what I am missing here. How can I get large metadata_properties of a translated file?

Answer (score 0):

Your function call looks strange. the last two arguments should be true/false, not key-value. i.e.,

```cs
GetModelviewPropertiesAsync(
  ForgeFileURN,                                                                             
  viewGUID,
  "gzip",                                                                            
  null,
  false,
  true
);
```

Here is the function delaration:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Returns a list of properties for each object in an object tree. Properties are returned according to object ID and do not follow a hierarchical structure.  The following image displays a typical list of properties for a Revit object:  ![](https://developer.doc.autodesk.com/bPlouYTd/7/_images/Properties.png)  To call this endpoint you need to first call the [GET {urn}/metadata](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET) endpoint, which returns a list of model view (metadata) IDs for a design input model. Select a model view (metadata) ID to use when calling the Get Properties endpoint.  Note that you can only get properties from a design input file that was previously translated into an SVF file. 
/// </remarks>
/// <exception cref="Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException">Thrown when fails to make API call</exception>
/// <param name="urn">The Base64 (URL Safe) encoded design URN </param>
/// <param name="guid">Unique model view ID. Call [GET {urn}/metadata](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET) to get the ID </param>
/// <param name="acceptEncoding">If specified with &#x60;gzip&#x60; or &#x60;*&#x60;, content will be compressed and returned in a GZIP format.  (optional)</param>
/// <param name="objectid">Object id which you want to query properties for.</param>
/// <param name="xAdsForce">If true - force retrieve the object tree even though it failed to be retrieved or got timeout (got 404 with error message) previously.</param>
/// <param name="forceget">If true - To force get the large resource even if it exceeded the expected maximum length (20 MB).</param>
/// <returns>Task of Metadata</returns>
System.Threading.Tasks.Task</*Metadata*/dynamic> GetModelviewPropertiesAsync(string urn, string guid, string acceptEncoding = null, List<int> objectIds = null, bool xAdsForce = false, bool forceget = false);
```

Comment: My last arguments are false and true. I just mentioned the variable name for better understanding. it is just as you mentioned
GetModelviewPropertiesAsync(
  ForgeFileURN,                                                                             
  viewGUID,
  "gzip",                                                                            
  null,
  false,
  true
);
still getting the same error.

Comment: Got it, please see [PR#91](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/pull/91) of the `forge-api-dotnet-client`. Before it gets merged, please consider compiling the updated version [here](https://github.com/yiskang/forge-api-dotnet-client/tree/fix-duplicate-forceget).